# Get iFrame to full width of website (not content!)

Tags: html, css, iframe

My Iframe code looks like:

```
<style type="text/css">
#left {
display: none;
float: left;
width: 212px;
}
#right {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 100%;
}</style>
<div align="left">
<iframe height="1000" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=YjN4gDN/case_portal" width="2000"></iframe></div>
```

However I'd like to expand the iFrame area to the entire width of the page, so it fills an area like:

[image: full width image]

If I simply increase the width of the iframe I end up with the following:

[image: current issue]

**How can I achieve the first image without encountering the second images problems?**

You can see the page - [here](http://www.workbooks.com/portal-test).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, increase width of `#content-sub` to `100%` (it's `960px` now; your frame is one of its children, so to stretch it to full width you have to get parent node stretched the same way). Second, change `iframe` as follows:
`<iframe height="1000" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=YjN4gDN/case_portal" style="width:100%"></iframe>`

Comment: Unfortunately while this worked for this individual page, it also applied the same to all my other pages. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ideally, I'd be able to do this by editing the <style> I've applied to the individual page.

Comment: If possible, edit your source so that only on this page `div` with `#content-sub` id will be also styled with class: `<div id ="content-sub" class="fullwidth">`, plus CSS: `.fullwidth {
width: 100%
}`
Or you can add `style` attribute instead of `class`: `<div id ="content-sub" style="width: 100%;">`

Comment: I'm really sorry, I don't understand this. Please confirm what I need to add, where.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Could you please expand upon your answer?

Comment: `body` tag on your site has some dymanic classnames. For http://www.workbooks.com/portal-test it is `section-portal-test` and it seems to be unique for this page. I'm not that good at Drupal and can be wrong, but if it's so, the best way is to modify your iframe as stated in my first response and to add the following style to your CSS file:
`.section-portal-test #content-sub {
    width: 100%;
}
`

Comment: This pushed things to the right and didn't extend the width. I added a margin to the right and changed the width from a % back to pixels. This meant my styles.css addition looked like:    
    `.page-node-2289 #content-sub { 
    width: 1000px;
    margin-left: 75px
    }` **and my iframe code:** `<style type="text/css">
#left {
display: none;
float: left;
width: 212px;
}
#right {
display: block;
float: right;
width: 100%;
}</style>
<div align="left">
 <iframe height="1000" src="https://secure.workbooks.com/process/=YjN4gDN/case_portal" width="1200"></iframe></div>`

Comment: Thanks for your help, couldn't of done it without you. I also changed `.section-portal-test` to `.page-node-2289` since it references the node rather than the page title (yours did work though!)

Comment: Hm... Doesn't look like you got what you wanted. All you need is to set `width: 100%` for `.page-node-2289 #content-sub` in CSS (not `1000px` because this will work only for certain window width) and `style="width:100%"` for `iframe` tag (not `width="1200"` because of the same reason). Other code is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, worked on dev site, pushing live later this week. Will try the 100% approach again but it didn't seem to workout.